# Android how to use CursorLoader with multiple tables?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I have my database and ContentProvider all set up.  I'm trying to get all the data from my database using a CursorLoader, and I'm wondering how exactly I can do that for multiple tables. Do I create a separate fragment activity for each table and implement the cursorLoader?  And when do these activities get invoked so that I can use them?  Should I instantiate them within the MainActivity?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'all the data from my database'? Without your database schema, tables relations to one another, and an idea of what kind of UI you want to display, we can't really help can we?

Comment: I have 4 different tables, and what I want to do is create four arrayLists; each one containing an objects with fields of every row of a table.  Then I want to use the the objects in these arrayLists in various different parts of the application.